# Need Latitude longitude by clicking maps on specific location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google maps api for android apps development . when i will click on maps on specific location then i need the latitude and longitude of that location . in summary i need the specific locations latitude and longitude by clicking on maps (maybe one click or long click that is not an issue i just need the latitude and longitude).

Answer (score 0):

Call setOnMapClickListener in GoogleMap then you'll get LanLng when you click google map. LatLng contains latitude and longitude.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
        void onMapClick(LatLng latLng){
           //use latLng for latitude and longitude
        }
    });
```

Comment: its works . but need OnMapReady() callBack. i knew it is there any other option .